# Compile DAHDI on OpenVZ VPS: kernel issue

Tags: compilation, kernel, centos, asterisk, openvz

Kernel version:  `2.6.32-042stab057.1`

`rpm -qa | grep -i kernel` result:

```
vzkernel-headers-2.6.32-042stab057.1.i686
libreport-plugin-kerneloops-2.0.9-5.el6.centos.i686
vzkernel-firmware-2.6.32-042stab057.1.noarch
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.0.8-6.el6.centos.i686
vzkernel-devel-2.6.32-042stab057.1.i686
```

when i send the command make i get this error:

```
You do not appear to have the sources for the 2.6.32-042stab057.1 kernel installed.
```

OS: Centos 6.3 Final

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with OpenVZ, but from your provided information, looks like you don't have kernel source. You have kernel-devel and kernel-headers, but not the kernel itself.

You may download kernel here:
http://download.openvz.org/kernel/branches/rhel6-2.6.32/042stab057.1/vzkernel-2.6.32-042stab057.1.i686.rpm

And then: `rpm -ivh vzkernel-2.6.32-042stab057.1.i686.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue compiling it on my new VPS. I was able to get it all to install from the files found at http://wiki.openvz.org/Download/kernel/rhel6/042stab057.1
Download/install those RPMs and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need

1. have access to main node, compile asterisk on it
2. forward dahdi device to container(via container config)
3. copy from main node kernel-devel package, compile dahdi in container.

Read this

http://openvz.org/Asterisk_from_source